# Solutions of a system of polynomial equations

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find the critical points of some functions such as $$f(x, y) = x^4 − x^2y^2 + y^3 − 18x^2 + 3y^2$$ I calculate the gradient, and then find a system of polynomial equations: $$\operatorname{grad}(f(x,y)) = {4x^3-2xy^2-36x\choose-2x^2y+3y^2 + 6y}$$ Our teacher solves it by equaling $x = 0$ and then $y= 0$, which intuitively seems like we're "missing" some solutions. After solving it this way I can't help wondering if I've actually found all the solutions.

I was wondering how many solutions does such a system have in general ($n$ degree polynomials with $m$ variables), and what are some methods to solve them?

Comment: Have you tried factorising the two expressions in your gradient vector? what happens if you do this and set each to zero?

Comment: Yes that's how we solved it - we factorize by x and y and set each to zero, and we end up with four real solutions. My question is about the reasoning behind this : setting the variables equal to zero seems like we knew that the solutions would either be on the x or on the y axis, was it pure guessing or is it a general way of solving this type of system?

Comment: You're not setting x and y to zero, you're setting the x and y /components/ of the gradient vector to 0

Comment: Well, I get that. But I'm now talking about solving the system that this implies

Comment: well you just get two non-linear simultaneous equations in $x$ and $y$, there are many possible methods for these...

Comment: Yes but how many solutions do these kind of systems have in general? And how do I know that there aren't more solutions that thd four I have found? Because solving it the way we did (setting x=0, then y=0) doesn't feel satisfying in the sense that it seems that there could be more solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$4x^3-2xy^2-36x= 0 \implies 2x(2x^2-y^2-18)=0$$
$\implies x=0 $

or $2x^2-y^2-18 = 0$ (*)

$$-2x^2y+3y^2 + 6y \implies y(-2x^2+3y+6)=0$$

$\implies y=0 $

or $-2x^2+3y+6 = 0$ (**)

Putting $x=0$ in (**) gives $y=-2$, so one point is $(0,-2)$.

Putting $y=0$ in (*) gives $x=\pm3$, so we get two more points $(3,0)$ and $(-3,0)$.

Both equations are satisified for $x=0,y=0$ so we also get the origin as a point $(0,0)$

To find any more we need to solve (*) and (**) simultaneously. If we can, then along with the others we have found, that should be all the solutions.

From (*), $2x^2=y^2+18$ and substituting this into (**) gives 
$$-(y^2+18)+3y+6 =0 \implies y^2-3y +12=0$$ which has no real solutions (negative discriminant), so we have found the only 4 points and there are no more.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x,+y)+%3D+x%5E4+%E2%88%92+x%5E2y%5E2+%2B+y%5E3+%E2%88%92+18x%5E2+%2B+3y%5E2+stationary+points

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a last question : is it the way you usually solve systems like these, or do different methods exist?

Comment: This was broadly how I was taught, and have taught, how to do it!